# All Letters in String Appear in List

Tags: python, list, boolean

I am trying to determine if all letters in myString are found in myList. Here is my code so far.

```
def findLetters(myList,myString):
    myList = set(myList)
    myString = list(myString)
    myString = set(myString)
    for x in myString:
        if x not in myList:
            return bool (False)
        if x in myList:
            return bool (True)
```

One of the examples which should return True is the following:

> > findLetters(["hello","world"],"old")

However, I get False. Can someone explain where I went wrong?

Comment: What logic are you trying to implement? Do you want to test if "o", "l" and "d" appear in *any* of the words `['hello', 'world']` ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: `set(myString).issubset(set(sum(myList, [])))`

Comment: start by explaining to yourself, line by line, in English words, what the intended logic of the code is. In particular, exactly what do you expect `x in myList` to do; and how do you expect `return` to work in general?

Comment: That fails @StephenRauch for the test `findLetters(["hello","world"],"old")`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner in Python:

```
def findLetters(myList, myString):
    return set(myString) <= set(''.join(myList))
```

You had the right idea to convert both parameters to sets, just forgot to join the list of strings before... then set inclusion operator `<=` is very handy

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are comparing each letter to *words*.

In your example, `set(myList)` results in `{'hello', 'world'}`.  You then compare each letter in 'old' to this set. As you can see, this will fail (e.g. the letter 'o' is not in the set {'hello', 'world'} even though it is in a *word* in the set).

```
>>> 'o' in set(my_list)
False
```

You may find this useful, where your a set of unique letters are created from the list of words using a set comprehension, and then another set is taken of the unique letters in your string.

```
my_list = ["hello","world"]
my_string = 'old'

list_letters = {letter for letter in word for word in my_list}  # {'d', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'w'}
word_letters = set(my_string)  # {'d', 'l', 'o'}

>>> word_letters.issubset(list_letters)
# Output: True
```

Turning this into a one liner:

```
>>> set(my_string).issubset({letter for letter in word for word in my_list})
True
```

The other problem with your code is that you do not want to return `True` when it finds a letter in `my_list` (i.e. the last line of your code).  You can return `False` if a letter is not in `my_list`, but must then return `True` if you've iterated through all the letters, e.g.

```
for word in myList:
    if x not in word:
        return False
return True
```

You could also use `all`:

```
if all(x in word for word in myList):
    return True
return False  # Not really needed, since it would return None which is a falsey.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.

```
def findLetters(myList, myString):
    WordLetters = set(''.join(myList))
    StringLetters = set(myString)
    for s in StringLetters:
        yield s, s in WordLetters

res = list(findLetters(['hello', 'world'], 'old'))
# [('d', True), ('o', True), ('l', True)]

res2 = all(list(zip(*findLetters(['hello', 'world'], 'old')))[1])
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to determine if all letters in myString are found in myList.

You can use a combination of the built-in functions `any` and `all` to accomplish this:

```
>>> def findLetters(myList,myString):
    return all(any(c in word for word in myList) for c in myString)

>>> findLetters(["hello","world"],"old")
True
>>>
```